# Unable to create operator for generic class in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, operator-overloading

In Swift 4 I've created the following protocol to determine if something has a + operator inplemented

```
protocol Addable { static func +(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self }
```

Now I've created a class named `Vector<T>` where `T` is of course a generic type.

```
class Vector<T: Addable>: Addable {
 var values: [T]

 init(values: [T]) {
  self.values = values
 }

 static func +(lhs: Vector<T>, rhs: Vector<T>) -> Self {
  return lhs
 }
}
```

The `return lhs` part of the + operator implementation is just temporary. But for some reason this gives me the following error:
`Cannot convert return expression of type 'Vector<T>' to return type 'Self'`

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? I haven't got a clue.

Comment: It looks like compiler bug. Like, if you replace `class Vector<T>` with `struct Vector<T>` it works just fine. Maybe it has something to do with inheritance in classes or something.

Comment: Ok, `final class` works too. It fails definitely because class can be inherited and `Self` points to either Vector<T> or to any of it's subclasses.

Comment: Alright thanks for the help!

Comment: This should be written up as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Moved from comments:*

Problem is caused by class inheretability. It looks like Swift cannot infer returning `Self` type for non-final classes, because `Self` in current class and in it's subclasses mean different. But for some reason there's no such problem with `Self` in parameters.

And solutions to this problem are:

- make class `final`, and set returning `Self` to the proper type and it will work
- replace `class` with `struct`, and set proper type
- add `associatedtype` that is `Self` by default:

  ```
  protocol Addable {
      associatedtype S = Self
      static func + (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> S
  }
  ```

  Latter option will work with non-final classes, but associated type should be checked that it's still equal to `Self`.